# How to adapt Highlighted content webpart on my own webpart using Sharepoint Framework?

Tags: sharepoint, frameworks, spfx

I'm currently developping my own sharepoint Framework webpart and I would like to use the exact same properties than the Highlighted content webpart natively available on sharepoint. Escpecially "content" and "Filter and sort" group in the property pane. But as I'm new to sharepoint developement I would like to know if there is the source code somewhere or something similar that I can use to help me.

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

Well you can achieve it parts.

Use cascading dropdowns in web part properties

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-cascading-dropdowns-in-web-part-properties

You can also use other checkbox and button in property pane.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/customizing-sharepoint-framework-web-part-properties-part-two/